# Space in Hive output

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want my Query output whitespace separate. I just want output fields to be separated only by one space. I used the below settings but I get ABC ^A 9000. So, there is ^A in between.

How can I do one space between fields?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/stg/hive_training'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS terminated by''
```

Comment: Why can't you use tabs? Do none of the fields really contain spaces? Also, you have `''` in your question, not a space

Answer (score 0):

Just use space. It works.

#### Demo

**hive**

```
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/test'
row format delimited
fields terminated by ' '
select 1,2,3
;
```

**bash**

```
</tmp/test/000000_0 od -Anone -a
   1  sp   2  sp   3  nl
```

Comment: Are you still here?